# Horizontal UIScrollView is not centering the current page

Tags: ios, swift

I would like to have a horizontal scroll layout which displays images. It works fine if setup 0, 0, 0 and 0 the constraints of the `UIScrollView`. The problem is exactly when I change the constraints to make margins surrounded the `UIScrollView`. This is what happens:

[image: First image]
First image in the UIScrollView
[image: Second image]
Second image in the UIScrollView
[image: Third image]
Third image in the UIScrollView

As you can see, each time you scroll, more off-center the current page is.

I have tried to subtract trailing and leading constrains constants to the width of the scrollLayout, play with frames and bouds but without success.

If I run this example in a smaller display like iphone 5S, the problem is more pointed.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var pageController: UIPageControl!
    @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
    let imagesArray = ["b_1", "b_2", "b_3", "b_4", "b_5"]
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.scrollView.isPagingEnabled = true
        self.pageController.numberOfPages = imagesArray.count
        self.pageController.pageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.blue
        self.pageController.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.gray
        for i in 0...imagesArray.count - 1{
            let imageView = UIImageView()
            imageView.contentMode = .scaleToFill
            imageView.image = UIImage(named: self.imagesArray[i])
            let xPos = CGFloat(i)*self.view.bounds.size.width
            imageView.frame = CGRect(x: xPos, y: 0, width: view.frame.size.width, height: self.scrollView.frame.size.height )
            self.scrollView.contentSize.width = view.frame.size.width*CGFloat(i+1)
            self.scrollView.addSubview(imageView)
        }
    }

    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        let page = scrollView.contentOffset.x/scrollView.frame.width
       self.pageController.currentPage = Int(page)
    }


}
```

So, I would like to know how to always obtain the current image centered.

Thank you

EDITED with Rajesh results and view debug:

[image: REsult 1]
[image: REsult 2]
[image: REsult 3]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using a `UICollectionView` in place of a `UIScrollView` - otherwise you will be building a lot of the basics from scratch. You can use a collection view that centers the images, make sure paging is enabled and you should get the interface you're looking for. Make sure to adopt / conform to the `UICollectionViewDelegate` & `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` protocols with your view controller & set those delegates on your collection view. Hope that helps! Best of luck.